# Create image in gd library

Tags: php, ajax

I am copying image over an image using GD library But it is not showing properly. This is my code:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreate(288,288);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 230, 248, 248);
$file = 'images/smiley/smile'.$_POST['smiley'].'.png'; 
$bg = imagecreatefrompng($file);
imagealphablending($bg, true); 
imagesavealpha($bg, true);
imagecopymerge($im, $bg, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 25);
?>
```

i cannot upload image due to not enough reputation but i can explain that when i have a smiley where i have to overlap over an other image but when i run this function a grey color box overlap on the image instead of smiley. Smiley is also in grey color.

Please help...

This is the link for the image create after function runs

http://classicsouls.com/main/9695.png

I want to overlap this image

http://classicsouls.com/main/smile7.png

Comment: Please post a link to your image hosted on, say, [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) and someone will edit it into your post for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `imagealphablending` also for `$im`:

```
$im = imagecreate(288,288);
imagealphablending($im, true); 
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 230, 248, 248);
$file = 'images/smiley/smile'.$_POST['smiley'].'.png'; 
$bg = imagecreatefrompng($file);
imagealphablending($bg, true); 
imagesavealpha($bg, true);
imagecopymerge($im, $bg, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 25);
```